# Why does Apache return 403

Tags: apache

Why can't I see why Apache returns 403?!

If I look in the access log the only information I get is

```
193.162.142.166 - - [29/Jan/2014:18:34:26 +0100] "POST /api_test/callback.php HTTP/1.1" 403 2293
```

How can I get more information about why the request is forbidden/rejected?

The call is made from a payment gateway...

- If the callback URL is a `http` request there are no problems and returns `200 OK`
- If the callback URL is a `https` my server returns 403.. I need to know why?

The server has SSL and openSSL installed and it works!

Have tried to do the `https` request from http://web-sniffer.net/ and then there are no problems..

I don't get it.. There must be something in the request headers from the payment gateway which results in 403

## update

error log

```
[Wed Jan 29 20:45:55 2014] [error] No hostname was provided via SNI for a name based virtual host
```

## solution

Ok it looks like the client doesn't support SNI

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need to know why the server returns 403.. I think its something in the request headers which is the problem..

Comment: Is this from `/var/log/httpd/access_log`? And for your web server? If so, then this is a request from `193.162.142.166` to your server as a `POST /api_test/c` and your server rejected the request as being "forbidden". That's probably a good thing unless you really do have a `/api_test/c` in your server you want random people to access. I have a web server and I get people from all over the world making all sorts of weird access attempts. Mostly bots or hackers.

Comment: question updated with error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`LogLevel`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel) directive to adjust how verbose the error logs are and increase until you can see what you want.

httpd 2.4 has better messages in a lot of respect and expensive list of LogLevel settings than [2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel).  So if you're using 2.2 it may be a bit harder to figure this out.